# How to check for an empty Optional array of strings in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, option-type

How can I check for an empty Optional array of strings in Java?

In the case is empty I would like to return a message.

```
@PostMapping("/users")
@ResponseBody
public String saveUsers(@RequestParam Optional<String>[] paramArray) {
    System.out.println("param " + paramArray);
    String msg = "";
    int i = 0;
    if (paramArray is empty) {
        msg = "paramArray is empty";
    } else {
        for (Optional<String> paramArrayItem : paramArray) {
            msg += "param[" + i + "]" + paramArrayItem + "\n";
            i++;
        }
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: It isn't an optional array of strings, but rather an array of optional strings. Anyway, in both cases, it's a bit odd, why don't you go with either an array of strings or a list of strings directly?

Comment: Depending on the desired behaviour, you could annotate the parameter with `@NotEmpty` and the controller with `@Validated`, Spring would do the heavy lifting for you and return a 400. You'll also save yourself a lot of syntactical trouble by making the parameter a `List<String>`, you should get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Optional<String>[]` is an array of `Optional<String>` elements.

You'd rather want to have optional array of strings, so you need to change `paramArray` type to `Optional<String[]>`.

```
@PostMapping("/users")
@ResponseBody
public String saveUsers(@RequestParam Optional<String[]> paramArray) {
    System.out.println("param " + paramArray);
    String msg = "";
    int i = 0;
    if (paramArray.isEmpty()) {
        msg = "paramArray is empty";
    } else {
        for (String paramArrayItem : paramArray.get()) {
            msg += "param[" + i + "]" + paramArrayItem + "\n";
            i++;
        }
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting java: cannot find symbol -> symbol:   method isEmpty() ->  location: variable paramArray of type java.util.Optional<java.lang.String[]> @vszholobov

Comment: @Pep this [method was added since java 11 version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty():~:text=present%2C%20otherwise%20false-,isEmpty,-public%C2%A0boolean%C2%A0isEmpty) . You could use `!paramArray.isPresent()` instead on lower versions